# Router.push to the newly created Record (NextJS/Supabase) -> returns nothing

Tags: javascript, next.js, supabase

I am building an application where people can register shipments from/to locations.
When a user creates a new shipment, they should be able to save it and then add goods.

I've build the system in such a way, that ones the data is submitted to Supabase it should return the ID and use that to Router.push the next page.
However.. it does not route there.

This is the code of the handleSubmit function:

```
const router = useRouter()
const [id2, setId] = useState('')

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (!location_to_city || !location_to_country || !location_from_city || !location_from_country) {
            setFormError('Please fill in all the fields correctly')
            return
        }

        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('shipment')
            .insert([{ location_from_address_1, location_from_zipcode, location_from_city, location_from_country, location_to_address_1, location_to_zipcode, location_to_city, location_to_country, customs, excise, dangerous_goods, documents, documents_information, user_id: user.id }])
            .select()

        console.log(data)
        setId(data.id)
        console.log(id2)

        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            setFormError('Please fill in all the fields correctly')
        }

        if (data) {
            setFormError(null)
            
        }

        router.push('/shipments/' + id2)
    }
```

Once this has been entered, the console.log(data) looks like this:

```
active
: 
true
created_at
: 
"2022-12-23T10:40:13.783891+00:00"
customs
: 
false
dangerous_goods
: 
false
documents
: 
false
documents_information
: 
""
excise
: 
false
id
: 
81
location_from_address_1
: 
""
location_from_city
: 
"a"
location_from_country
: 
"b"
location_from_zipcode
: 
""
location_to_address_1
: 
""
location_to_city
: 
"c"
location_to_country
: 
"d"
location_to_zipcode
: 
""
user_id
: 
"00063c91-f745-4a74-ba86-90603b84bed5"
```

But the url looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/shipments/

Does anyone know how I can get the ID value to be added to the url I use in router.push?

Answer (score 0):

because id2 is still equals to `''` for this render, it will change but in the next one

you can push like this instead :

```
 router.push('/shipments/' + data[0].id)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I see it now indeed.

I solved it in the following way: the response of the .select() of Supabase is in the first object. So the correct usage is:

router.push('/shipments/' + data[0].id)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way:

The response of the `.select()` function from Supabase is in the first object. So the correct usage is:

```js
router.push(`shipments/` + data[0].id)
```